# Is there anything in RHEL 6.5 that would affect I/O speed for something <24K vs >24K?

Tags: rhel, memory, swap

Generally, transactions for my app of setting and getting data internally are measured in a couple of millis. However, over 24K in size, that time can jump to just over 100 millis.

Is there anything in RHEL 6.5 64-bit that could cause that drastic of a change? Some strange I/O thing that dumps bigger objects to swap vs. memory, having to allocate multiple blocks, etc.?

Comment: You need to provide more details. What transactions, what 24K?

Comment: Smaller reads are more likely to occur at all once in real time, whereas larger reads are more likely to end being interrupted by the scheduler.  At that point you will introduce a relatively significant delay.  If this is **network I/O** (you've provided very little information), the size of the underlying socket buffer might impact this scheduling as the buffer is emptied and refilled; these are usually between 16 and 64 kB.

Comment: Yeah... I know I haven't provided much. I was looking for a needle in a haystack, and I apologize. I think that I've actually found the issue in Jetty. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031311/slow-transfers-in-jetty-with-chunked-transfer-encoding-at-certain-buffer-size